# How to rename a variable in file only with VS code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, refactoring, rename

I have a lot of unrelated files open and when I try F2, it says there is syntax is 99 files, which there is, but it does not matter, since they are unrelated.

How do I only change in one python file?

Comment: F2 is the keyboard shortcuts set to **Rename Symbol** and **renameFile**. To change the specific file name, choose it and right click to make changes.